# jQuery loop through a List

Tags: jquery

I have a list as follows:

```
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

I have a textbox whose entered value I am getting in a variable named `get`. Now, I want to loop through this list using jquery and want to compare `get`'s value with the matched values of the list. If they are matching, I have to print them in a label.

Comment: I can see no jQuery code. Please post what you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var getsValue = $.trim( $("#getId").val() );
var matchedList = [];
$("ul > li").each(function() {
  if( getsValue == $(this).text().substr(0,1) ) { //check first character
     //found -- do something
     //add to matched list array
     matchedList.push( $(this).text());
  }
});
```

Or its better if you add id to ul, so you can do:

```
$("ul#someId > li").each(function() { ...
```

To check if a character is contained, you can use indexOf, like:

```
console.log(someString.indexOf("T")); //will return position if found else -1
```

Do you mean something like that

Comment: Why do you use `$.trim( $("#getId").val() )` when you could simply use `$("#getId").val().trim();`?

Comment: @DavidThomas IE8 and below do not support the `trim` method.

Comment: @DavidThomas thats kinda habit, and infact hadn't used .trim() before

Comment: Thanks.it is working.How can i matched a Entered character Suppose "T" with the list items.So if matching occur ,all items starting with "T" will be printed in labels.

Comment: you can use indexOf to check if character is contained...see added code

Comment: Actually user have to enter only one character in textbox.We need to match that with 1st character of list values and print matched one.

Answer (score 0):

to loop through the list items, use jquery's each() function. Try:

```
var get = "Tea"; //or other value
$('li').each(function(index) {
    if($(this).text()==get){
   //doMagic();
    }

});​
```